# For Loop for data frame to add rows in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I need to add and run the current coding using for loop..

```
df<-data.frame("hi","bye")
names(df)<-c("hello","goodbye")

de<-data.frame("hola","ciao")
names(de)<-c("hello","goodbye")

newdf <- rbind(df, de)
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code? Is there an error?

Comment: I really don't understand the question, there's nothing to be done, your code adds (`rbind`) one df to the other.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't figure out why, anyway just run the following

```
newdf = data.frame(hello=character(), goodbye=character()); # create the empty data.frame

# add each df row (one by one)
for(i in 1:NROW(df)) {
    newdf[i, ] = df[i, ];
}

# add each de row (one by one)
for(i in 1:NROW(df)) {
    newdf[i+NROW(df), ] = de[i, ];
}
```